# How ASPX class is generated

Tags: asp.net

I understand page life cycle, but little bit unclear of how ASPX is parsed and class is generated for it. I have read that parser generates class containing controls declared in .aspx page and compiler creates a dll. I need more detail on it and have one query around this. Partial classes have to be in 1 assembly. If my code behind is another assembly (which was generated I compiled my web app) then how partial class generated by ASP.NET compiler (for aspx page) is merged with it?

Answer (score 0):

All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

know more ,read link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx